# addin markets points to GMAPs from C# JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, google-maps

Good morning guys,

I am creating a application based on GMaps Geolocation.

I have the Lat and the Long in my database. 
I created a JSON with the data I need to pass to Javascript but when I try to call the JSON file in my Javascript it is not adding the markers..

CS Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Reflection;

namespace testeMapa
{
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MySqlConnection mConn;
    private MySqlDataAdapter mAdapter;
    private DataSet mDataSet;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mConn = new MySqlConnection("server=*****;User Id=*****;database=*****; password=*****");
        mConn.Open();

        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
        com.Connection = mConn;
        com.CommandText = "Select idDado, latitudeEnd, longitudeEnd, enderecoDado from inserirDados";
        MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);



    }


        [WebMethod]
    static public string Carregar(DataTable dt )
    {


        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }

            var pontos = jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);


            return pontos;

        }
        }
    }
```

My JSon is in the format below:

```
[
 {
"idDado": 11,
"latitudeEnd": "-22.8668838",
"longitudeEnd": "-43.307824100000005",
"enderecoDado": "R. Limeira, 16 - Tomás Coelho, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 21370-     460, Brasil"
},
{
  "idDado": 10,
  "latitudeEnd": "-22.9501581",
  "longitudeEnd": "-43.18422179999999",
  "enderecoDado": "Botafogo - Botafogo, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil"
}
  ]
```

And My JavaScript:

```
var map;
var idInfoBoxAberto;
var infoBox = [];
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

var options = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
}

initialize();

function abrirInfoBox(id, marker) {
if (typeof (idInfoBoxAberto) == 'number' && typeof (infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto]) == 'object') {
    infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto].close();
}

infoBox[id].open(map, marker);
idInfoBoxAberto = id;
}

function carregarPontos() {



    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'testeMapa/index.aspx/Carregar',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (pontos) {

            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            $(pontos).each(function (i) {

                var lat = pontos[i].latitudeEnd;
                var long = pontos[i].longitudeEnd;
                var endereco = pontos[i].enderecoDado;
                var idDados = pontos[i].idDado;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                    title: "Meu ponto personalizado! :-D",
                    icon: 'img/marcador.png'
                });

                var myOptions = {
                    content: "<p>" + endereco + "</p>",
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, 0)
                };

                infoBox[idDados] = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                infoBox[idDados].marker = marker;

                infoBox[idDados].listener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                    abrirInfoBox(idDados, marker);
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        }  });

}

carregarPontos();
```

I am new at this C# and JavaScript thing.. so It may have a lot of mistakes..
The map is showing, but no points are added.

Could you guys help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4ae82p8/ Do you have any error in browser log? Maybe path to image `img/marcador.png` does not exists? Have you included all required libraries: `markerclusterer.js`, `infobox.js`?

Comment: Yes I did.. when I use the file pontos.json it works fine.. but when I try to make from the json I created on function Carregar it does not show anything..

Comment: what did you put in the 'https://demo3420490.mockable.io/caregear' ?

Thanks a lot.. I think you are helping me a lot!

Comment: I think my error is in the URL line.. because when I changed it to 'https://demo3420490.mockable.io/caregear', it worked.. but olny with the two points I passed in the example

Comment: I have mocked your server response using https://demo3420490.mockable.io/caregear. If you make HTTP POST to it ( eg, using http://requestmaker.com/) you will see that it only returns JSON data from the question. Therefore it appears that either your server URL is not OK, or the JSON returned is not OK. Use browser console to check it.

Comment: Thanks again for your support. The 2 points I inserted here was the output from my JSON.. What should I put in the url.?

Comment: Then there must be some error in browse console. Can you check that?

Comment: a lot of errors appeared.. http://localhost:3264/index.aspx/Carregar Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Your `[WebMethod]` `static public string Carregar(DataTable dt )`expects `DataTable dt` as input parameter, I do not see where do you supply it. Can you set `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` as global var (below `private DataSet mDataSet;`) and remove input params from `Carregar`, so it looks like this: `static public string Carregar()`?

Comment: now in dt.rows inside the webmethod it says "a reference of an object is necessary for the field, method or property index.dt not static"...

Comment: Aha, accessing the non-static var from static context is making issue. Try: `static DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

Comment: now the error in browse console is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitudeEnd' of undefined

Comment: Try changing `$(pontos).each(function (i) {` to `$.each(pontos, function(i, value) {`

Comment: an error has appeared: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded   and the map turns grey.. btw, I changed my Carregar function to a page http://www.buscmob.somee.com/listaDados.aspx/Carregar and when I do a console.log(pontos) it shows my JSON